# HQL, insert two rows if a condition is met

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I have the following table called table_persons in **Hive**:

```
+--------+------+------------+
| people | type | date       |
+--------+------+------------+
| lisa   | bot  | 19-04-2022 |
| wayne  | per  | 19-04-2022 |
+--------+------+------------+
```

**If type is "bot", I have to add two rows in the table d1_info else if type is "per" i only have to add one row** so the result is the following:

```
+---------+------+------------+
| db_type | info | date       |
+---------+------+------------+
| x_bot   | x    | 19-04-2022 |
| x_bnt   | x    | 19-04-2022 |
| x_per   | b    | 19-04-2022 |
+---------+------+------------+
```

How can I add two rows if this condition is met?
with a Case When maybe?

Comment: I noticed that you changed the 2nd occurence of the `x_bot` in `db_type` to `x_bnt`. Is this a typo or is this the desired output?

Comment: what did you end up using?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using a union to merge or duplicate the rows with `bot`. The following eg unions the first query which selects all records and the second query selects only those with `bot`.

**Edit**

In response to the edited question, I have added an additional parity column (storing `1` or `0`) named `original` to differentiate the duplicate entry named

```sql
    SELECT
        p1.*,
        1 as original
    FROM
        table_persons p1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p1.*,
        0 as original
    FROM
        table_persons p1
    WHERE p1.type='bot'
```

You may then insert this into your other table `d1_info` using the above query as a subquery or CTE with the desired transformations CASE expressions eg

```sql
INSERT INTO d1_info
  (`db_type`, `info`, `date`)
WITH merged_data AS (
    SELECT
        p1.*,
        1 as original
    FROM
        table_persons p1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p1.*,
        0 as original
    FROM
        table_persons p1
    WHERE p1.type='bot'
)
SELECT
    CONCAT('x_',CASE
           WHEN m1.type='per' THEN m1.type
           WHEN m1.original=1 AND m1.type='bot' THEN m1.type
           ELSE 'bnt'
    END) as db_type,
    CASE
       WHEN m1.type='per' THEN 'b'
       ELSE 'x'
    END as info,
    m1.date
FROM
    merged_data m1
ORDER BY m1.people,m1.date;
```

See working demo db fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eyt3taZuvRaRKnPKSvPzFh/4)

Comment: wow thank you ggordon! I have edited the post, maybe is indifferent but the two rows added would be one with x_bot and the other one with x_bnt. Works fine with this change?

Comment: @CCantona I've updated the answer in response to this edit and I have also updated the demo fiddle. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to create a new table that captures your logic.  This would simplify your query and make it so you could easily add new types without having to edit logic of a case statement.  It may also make it cleaner to view your logic later.

```
CREATE TABLE table_persons (
  `people` VARCHAR(5),
  `type` VARCHAR(3),
  `date` VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO table_persons
VALUES
  ('lisa', 'bot', '19-04-2022'),
  ('wayne', 'per', '19-04-2022');
  


CREATE TABLE info (
  `type` VARCHAR(5),
  `db_type` VARCHAR(5),
  `info` VARCHAR(1)
);

insert into info 
   values 
   ('bot', 'x_bot', 'x'), 
   ('bot', 'x_bnt', 'x'), 
   ('per','x_per','b');
```

and then you can easily do a join:

```
select 
  info.db_type, 
  info.info, 
  persons.date date 
from 
  table_persons persons inner join info 
on 
  info.type = persons.type
```